# sscanf function changes the content of another string

Tags: c, string, pointers, buffer-overflow, scanf

I am having problems reading strings with `sscanf`. I have dumbed down the code to focus on the problem. Below is a function in the whole code that is supposed to open a file and read something. But `sscanf` is acting strangely. For instance I declare a string called `atm` with the content `'ATOM'`. Before the `sscanf` it prints this string as `ATOM` while after it is null. What could be the problem? I assume it must be an allocation problem but I could not find it. I tried some suggestions on other topics like replacing `%s` with other things but it did not help.

```
 void Get (struct protein p, int mode, int type) 
 {
   FILE *fd; //input file
   char name[100]="1CMA"; //array for input file name
   char string[600]; //the array where each line of the data file is stored when reading
   char atm[100]="ATOM";
   char begin[4];
   int index1 =0;

   fd = fopen(name, "r"); // open the input file

   if(fd==NULL) {
     printf("Error: can't open file.\n");
     return 1;
   }    

   if( type==0 ) { //pdb file type
     if( mode==0 ) { 
       while( fgets(string, 600, fd)!=NULL ) {
         printf("1 %s\n",atm);
         sscanf (string, "%4s", begin );
         printf("2 %s \n",atm);
       }
     }   
   }
   fclose(fd);
   free(fd);
   free(name);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `begin` isn't big enough to hold the four characters that `sscanf` will read *and* its `\0` terminator.  If the `\0` is written into `atm` (depending on where the strings are in memory), `atm` would be modified.  From the [sscanf manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf), about the `s` directive:

> s    Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and  the  terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically.  The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

I was able to reproduce this behavior on my machine, though the exact positioning of the strings in memory was a bit different.  By printing the addresses of the strings, though, it is easy to figure exactly what's happening.  Here's a minimal example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() { 
  char begin[2];
  char atm[100]="ATOM";

  printf("begin:    %p\n", begin);
  printf("begin+16: %p\n", begin+16);
  printf("atom:     %p\n", atm);
  printf("1 %s\n",atm);
  sscanf("AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD", "%16s", begin);
  printf("2 %s \n",atm);
  return 0;
}
```

This produces the output:

```
$ ./a.out 
begin:    0x7fffffffe120
begin+16: 0x7fffffffe130
atom:     0x7fffffffe130
1 ATOM
2
```

I printed the values of the pointers to figure out how big a string it would take to overflow into `atm`.  Since (on my machine) `atom` begins at `begin+16`, reading sixteen characters into `begin` puts a null terminator at `begin+16`, which is the first character of `atm`, so now `atm` has length 0.

Comment: Thank you that was indeed the problem and the post was very instructive.

Comment: @Sina Glad to help!  I almost started the answer with "Congratulations on your successful initiation into the Buffer Overflow Club, one of the largest profession programmer associations!", but sometimes humor doesn't come across in text.  These are the sorts of bugs that are very easy to write, and are probably lurking in many lines of code out there.  Glad we got to catch one today! :)

Comment: thank you, actually I had a message way back about matlab :p I usually hangout in the math section.

A follow up question, since I am using tcc compiler it is hard to catch these bugs, especially when the code gets too long, I have even seen instances where the compiler also missed these errors and was even persuaded to write to the fourth entry of a three dimensional array which takes days to find. Is there any compiler or debugger which you could advise to catch such errors?

Comment: @Sina There are compilers out there (and compiler plugins) that attempt to detect some buffer overflows, but I haven't used any of them.  Sorry I can't be of more help on that front.