# strange anomaly with fscanf and the order of variable declaration

Tags: c, variables, declaration, scanf

I have this code to read a file and parse everything into a list of persons:

```
PersonList *parseFile(FILE* file) {
  PersonList *list = newPersonList();

  int r;
  do {
    char fname[50];
    char name[50];
    char gender;
    int birthYear;
    int deathYear;

    r = fscanf(file, "%50s %50s %1s %d %d", fname, name, &gender, &birthYear, &deathYear);
    printf("%s %s %c %d %d\n", fname, name, gender, birthYear, deathYear);

    // Stuff I want to do in future
  } while (r != EOF);

  return list;
}
```

The file has the format like this:

Alexander Wallner m 1922 1957 Bertram Hohlbichler 1905 Hermine Wallner 1904

string string char int int string string int string string int

So, I try to get the person and after that the parents. The strange thing is that *printf* doesn't print out the *fname* of the person. If I change the order of *fname* and *name* in *fscanf* than the first string is saved in *name*, but the second not in *fname*.
This curiosity depends on the order of the declaration of *faname* and *name* in line 5,6. If I turn them around, *name* isn't filled any more. What the hack is that? Why I can't save any string in *fname*?
Hope that someone can explain this strange behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: My solution for now is the declaration of char foo[10] before fname. It works but that is not a proper programming :(

Comment: This is the same type of problem discussed (and answered) in [sscan function changes the content of another string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16593175/1281433).  The `*scanf` functions, when reading strings, write a `\0` terminator which, unless there's enough space in the buffer being written to, can end up being written into other buffers.  It's a simple buffer overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%c` for reading a `char` and not `%1s` as `%s` *always* writes a null terminator so the code has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), meaning anything can happen, as it is writing beyond the "bounds" of `gender`. Equally, when `printf()`ing use `%c` for variables of type `char` (as you correctly have).

The width in the format specifier `%Ns` must be one less than the target buffer to allow for the null terminating character.
Change to:

```
r = fscanf(file, "%49s %49s %c %d %d", ...
                /* ^^   ^^   ^ */
```

Before using the variables assigned by `fscanf()` ensure they have actually been assigned by checking the result of `fscanf()`, which returns the number of successful assignments made (in this case `5` is expected):

```
if (r == 5)
{
    printf("%s %s %c %d %d\n", fname, name, gender, birthYear, deathYear);
}
```

Comment: I'd advise using `%1s` for the gender and make it a `char [2]` variable. This way you can rely on `printf` to skip blanks.

Comment: @Spidey Since the conversion specifiers are separated by whitespace, that is guaranteed to happen here with `%c` too.

Comment: You are right, the skipping part it tied to the space on the format itself, not on the field specifier. Roger.

Comment: so, the only error was the possible overflow. the reduction of 50 to 49 was enough to solve the problem. omg. could never imagine that this could be a mistake, especially because the names would never be filled completely. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PhantomasPhantom, not only that. Changing `%1s` to `%c` was the more probable cause.